# Why doesn't this button behave like the span?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

In the code : [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0sbo1393b3), The only thing that changes between these two elements is:

```
span
```

instead of

```
button
```

What I need is the button fill all the navbar height, like the span one (no red background visible).

Why it does not?

```html
<div class="top-0 flex h-20 w-full justify-between bg-white">
  <span class="flex bg-red-400">
    <a class="flex items-center bg-green-400 px-6">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </a>
  </span>

  <button class="flex bg-red-400">
    <a class="flex items-center bg-green-400 px-6">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </a>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because according to docs of [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) and [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

> ###### The  HTML element is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything. It can be used to group elements for styling purposes (using the class or id attributes)

`span` is having properties which is specified here `flex`. Try removing class `flex` from `span` you'll observe the span is also using only the height required by `a` tag. `flex` is the class which is pushing the `span` to complete height of `parent`

##### Output span without `flex` class:

[image]

Whereas in the `button` it has its own attribute and is not as fuild as `span` is, by default it uses only the height required by the child. For this to have the entire `height` you should explicitly specify the height

---

#### Solution

Use: `h-full` inside the `<a>` tag of `<button>`

or

change `button` to `div`

#### Output:

[image]

#### Code:

```
<div class="top-0 flex h-20 w-full justify-between bg-white">
  <span class="flex bg-red-400">
    <a class="flex items-center bg-green-400 px-6">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </a>
  </span>

  <button class="flex bg-red-400">
    <a class="flex h-full items-center bg-green-400 px-6">  add h-full hear for a to use the entire height
      <span>Hello</span>
    </a>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I cannot change the `a` element class? (are not components I control)

Comment: Change `button` to `div`, I have edited my answer to give possible detailed explanation, I assume I have conviced you with this details , the proper working of <span> and <button> by providing document reference. Hope it helps